# Can't get an error in VB6 on Windows 7 while I can on Windows Xp

Tags: windows-7, vb6, windows-xp

I must correct some trouble on a program which is made in VB6.

When I try to print a file in XPS type and then I close the folder selection box the program give me a "Run time error 482".

So I decide to get the error with this :

```
On Error GoTo Error_Handler
```

It works on Windows XP, the run time error doesn't appear but under Windows 7 (64 bits) the program didn't respond.

I have no idea why it works on a side and not on the other

I have try to run, on Windows 7, the software in Windows XP compatibility but it doesn't work

```
Public Sub Print_All_Click()
Dim prntLePrinter As Printer
Dim iI As Integer

    For Each prntLePrinter In Printers
        iI = iI + 1
    Next

    On Error GoTo Error_Handler

    If (iI > 0) Then
        MousePointer = vbHourglass
        'CD Référence d'échelle pour l'imprimante
        Printer.ScaleHeight = 100
        Printer.ScaleWidth = 100
        'CD Configuration de la font
        Printer.FontName = "Arial"
        Printer.FontSize = 8
        Printer.FontBold = False
        Printer.FontItalic = False
        Printer.FontUnderline = False
        Printer.FontStrikethru = False
        Printer.FontTransparent = True
        Printer.Font.Charset = 0

        If g_nbSessions = 1 Then 'Mode NORMAL
            PrintHEADER
            PrintGeneral
            PrintExceedances
            PrintEpc
            PrintAlarms
            PrintMfdPages
            PrintEndReport

        Else 'Mode CUMUL
            PrintHEADERCumul
            PrintCUMUL
            PrintEndReportCumul
        End If

        Printer.EndDoc

        MousePointer = vbDefault

    Else
        MsgBox "No printer installed !", vbOKOnly, Frm_Main.Caption

    End If

Error_Handler:

    If MousePointer <> vbDefault Then
        MousePointer = vbDefault
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Use `iI = Printers.Count` instead of the first `For Each` loop. Which method jumps to the error handler on XP?

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I find a solution for my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution.

I have to use "Clear" to explicitly clear the Err object after treatment of an error, and then when I want to close the "selection folder box" the program close it correctly on Windows XP and on Windows 7.

So if you use `On Error GoTo Error_Handler`

don't forget to use :

```
Error_Handler:
```

And :

```
Err.Clear
```

My code now :

```
Public Sub Print_All_Click()
Dim prntLePrinter As Printer
Dim iI As Integer

    For Each prntLePrinter In Printers
        iI = iI + 1
    Next

    On Error GoTo Error_Handler

    If (iI > 0) Then
        MousePointer = vbHourglass
        'CD Référence d'échelle pour l'imprimante
        Printer.ScaleHeight = 100
        Printer.ScaleWidth = 100
        'CD Configuration de la font
        Printer.FontName = "Arial"
        Printer.FontSize = 8
        Printer.FontBold = False
        Printer.FontItalic = False
        Printer.FontUnderline = False
        Printer.FontStrikethru = False
        Printer.FontTransparent = True
        Printer.Font.Charset = 0

        If g_nbSessions = 1 Then 'Mode NORMAL
            PrintHEADER
            PrintGeneral
            PrintExceedances
            PrintEpc
            PrintAlarms
            PrintMfdPages
            PrintEndReport

        Else 'Mode CUMUL
            PrintHEADERCumul
            PrintCUMUL
            PrintEndReportCumul
        End If

        Printer.EndDoc

        MousePointer = vbDefault

    Else
        MsgBox "No printer installed !", vbOKOnly, Frm_Main.Caption

    End If

Error_Handler:
Err.Clear

    If MousePointer <> vbDefault Then
        MousePointer = vbDefault
    End If

End Sub
```